# RAML datatype fragment with multiple types

Tags: mulesoft, mule-esb, raml

I am trying to write a RAML data type fragment that would strictly define how selectedDate should be accepted

```
#%RAML 1.0 DataType
properties:
    selectedDate?:
        type: array | date-only
        example: ["2020-08-05", "2020-08-06"]
example:
    selectedDate: "2020-08-05"
```

User can send the date in string as date-only or an array, as shown in the two examples above.
But I need to allow the date in a date-only format, even when its sent in an array. But here array allows strings as well that are not dates.

I feel I am not explaining it well. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the array to be an [array based on a type for the elements](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md#array-type) by adding the `[]` suffix to the type: `date-only[]`. You can also encapsulate that definition into a new type.